# Ugrade to 16.04, 'p' key does not work anymore

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 16.04, keys

I just updated to 16.04. <kbd>P</kbd> key is not working anymore.

It seem like it is grabbed by `gnome-shell`

I tried this command:

```
xdotool keydown "p"; xdotool key "XF86LogGrabInfo"; xdotool keyup "p"
```

It outputs the following logs:

```
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]: (II)  Printing all currently active device grabs:
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]: Active  grab 0x41039c06 (xi2) on device 'Virtual core keyboard' (3):
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       client pid 6279 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       at 13373454 (from passive grab) (device frozen, state 6)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       xi2 event mask for device 3: 0xc000
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       passive grab type 2, detail 0x21, activating key 33
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       owner-events false, kb 0 ptr 1, confine 0, cursor 0x0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]: (II) End list of active device grabs
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]: Printing all currently registered grabs
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6149 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/bamf/bamfdaemon
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6180 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6205 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-ui-gtk3
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6207 /usr/lib/ibus/ibus-x11 --kill-daemon
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6235 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 7628 update-notifier
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 1839 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6279 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   grab 0x41000802 (xi2), type 'ButtonPress' on window 0x2c00001
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     detail 1 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 8 (mask 0)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     device 'Virtual core pointer' (2), modifierDevice 'Virtual core keyboard' (3)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       xi2 event mask 0x70 0 0 0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     owner-events false, kb 1 ptr 1, confine 0x0, cursor 0x0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   grab 0x41000803 (xi2), type 'ButtonPress' on window 0x2c00001
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     detail 1 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 10 (mask 0)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     device 'Virtual core pointer' (2), modifierDevice 'Virtual core keyboard' (3)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       xi2 event mask 0x70 0 0 0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     owner-events false, kb 1 ptr 1, confine 0x0, cursor 0x0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   grab 0x41000806 (xi2), type 'ButtonPress' on window 0x2c00001
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     detail 2 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 8 (mask 0)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     device 'Virtual core pointer' (2), modifierDevice 'Virtual core keyboard' (3)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       xi2 event mask 0x70 0 0 0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     owner-events false, kb 1 ptr 1, confine 0x0, cursor 0x0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   grab 0x41000807 (xi2), type 'ButtonPress' on window 0x2c00001
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     detail 2 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 10 (mask 0)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     device 'Virtual core pointer' (2), modifierDevice 'Virtual core keyboard' (3)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       xi2 event mask 0x70 0 0 0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     owner-events false, kb 1 ptr 1, confine 0x0, cursor 0x0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   grab 0x41000804 (xi2), type 'ButtonPress' on window 0x2c00001
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     detail 1 (mask 0), modifiersDetail 24 (mask 0)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     device 'Virtual core pointer' (2), modifierDevice 'Virtual core keyboard' (3)
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:       xi2 event mask 0x70 0 0 0
...
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:     owner-events false, kb 1 ptr 0, confine 0x0, cursor 0x0
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6279 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6284 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6284 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 12953 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6429 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-alarm-notify
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 6428 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 17771 xdotool key XF86LogGrabInfo
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 13260 /usr/share/atom/atom --executed-from=/home/gandre/WIP/Aeroport/localeez-ghosts-runner --pid=13246
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 13260 /usr/share/atom/atom --executed-from=/home/gandre/WIP/Aeroport/localeez-ghosts-runner --pid=13246
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 7046 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 7046 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 7160 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=7046.0.760934881 --window-depth=24 --suppor
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 7160 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --channel=7046.0.760934881 --window-depth=24 --suppor
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]:   Printing all registered grabs of client pid 17594 dconf-editor
avril 25 12:46:33 ADVI0051 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[5992]: End list of registered passive grabs
```

EDIT:
<kbd>P</kbd> is not associated with anything in dconf: org.gnome.shell.keybindings.

Answer (score 2):

Well Shellshape (gnome extension) is the culprit. However, I can't see any bindings to <kbd>p</kbd> in its conf.